# How to make a legend continue onto more rows when no room?

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure, legend, word-wrap

I have a plot with mutliple lines and I want to display the legend below the box (`southoutside`). The problem is that currently my legend is too long to fit on a single line. Therefore the question is how do I get a line break in my legend?

Currently I generate the legend as follows:

```
hLegend = legend([l1,l2,l3,l4], 'This is a very, very long legend text', 'Test2', ...
                                'A bit longer', 'This is quite long');
set(hLegend,'Fontsize',8,'Location', 'southoutside', 'Orientation','horizontal');
```

then this occurs:

[image]

As you can see I have four lines (there might come more) and the first one has a very long name.

I want to keep the orientation this way to reduce figure space needed and I want to put an automatic line break if the legend exceeds the picture width (i.e. before `l3` or `l4`, here illustrated by the yellow or purple line).

Any ideas on this? I am using a plot width of 15.75 cm.

**Edit**

Thanks a lot for the answers so far. Although both of the answers provide some opportunities in splitting the legend into two lines, my main problem still occurs. If assuming now that the plot had more then four lines, lets say 20 and I want to have the legend southside horizontal in a way that it uses the least space, is there a way to split the legend not **within** one legend text, but **after** one entry. I generated a new figure generally depicting what I am looking for (its made in Paint so it really just shows the general idea).

[image]

**Edit 2**

The `columnlegend` package available in the Matlab File Exchange unfortunately does not support legends outside of the figure (at least the options are not specified in the description it only names the following possible locations: 'NorthWest', 'NorthEast', 'SouthEast', 'SouthWest'

Help is appreciated.

Comment: See: [`columnlegend`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27389-simonhenin-columnlegend)

Comment: @excaza, I want the legend outside of the plot, columnlegend does not provide that option, from the description:  possible values: 'NorthWest', 'NorthEast', 'SouthEast', 'SouthWest'

Comment: The latest version added them.

Comment: @excaza, sorry to bother again but I run into problems using columnlegend, how do you format the legend string so that it takes it ? I dont get it to work. Help is still very appreciated

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54095402/matlab-pie-chart-with-2-split-legends-r2017b/54118321#54118321

Answer (score 5):

#### Intro:

Here's a proof-of-concept of legend text wrapping, using some undocumented outputs of `legend` and the `MATLAB -> python` interface. I will first show the code and then provide a brief explanation of why/how it works.

This is done in MATLAB 2016a.

#### Code:

```
function q39456339
%% Definitions:
MAX_LENGTH_IN_CHARS = 20;
OPTION = 2;
%% Plot something:
x = 1:10;
figure('Position',[450 400 800 270]); 
plot(x,x,x,2*x,x,10-x,x,20-2*x);
%% Using python's TextWrapper to wrap entries:
% web(fullfile(docroot, 'matlab/matlab_external/call-python-from-matlab.html'))
switch OPTION
  case 1
    [~,hT] = legend({'This is a very, very long legend text', 'Test2', 'A bit longer', ...
      'This is quite long'},'Location', 'SouthOutside', 'Orientation','Horizontal',...
      'Fontsize',8,'Box','Off');
    texts = hT(arrayfun(@(x)isa(x,'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'),hT));
    wrapLegendTexts(texts,MAX_LENGTH_IN_CHARS);
  case 2
    hL = legend({'This is a very, very long legend text', 'Test2', 'A bit longer', ...
      'This is quite long'},'Location', 'SouthOutside', 'Orientation','Horizontal',...
      'Fontsize',8,'Interpreter','tex');
    TEX_NEWLINE = '\newline';
    addNewlinesThroughPython(hL, MAX_LENGTH_IN_CHARS, TEX_NEWLINE);
end

end

%% Helper functions:
function wrapLegendTexts(textObjs,maxlen)
  tw = py.textwrap.TextWrapper(pyargs('width', int32(maxlen)));
  for ind1 = 1:numel(textObjs)
    wrapped = cellfun(@char,cell(wrap(tw,textObjs(ind1).String)), 'UniformOutput', false);
    textObjs(ind1).Text.String = reshape(wrapped,[],1);
  end
end

function addNewlinesThroughPython(hLeg, maxlen, newlineStr)
  tw = py.textwrap.TextWrapper(pyargs('width', int32(maxlen)));
  for ind1 = 1:numel(hLeg.PlotChildren)
    hLeg.PlotChildren(ind1).DisplayName = char(...
      py.str(newlineStr).join(wrap(tw,hLeg.PlotChildren(ind1).DisplayName)));
  end
end
```

#### Result:

Option 1:
[image: Wrapping with option 1, maxlen 20]

Option 2:
[image: Wrapping with option 2, maxlen 20]

#### Explanation (Option 1):

First, let's look at the signature of `legend`:

```
>> dbtype legend 1

1     function [leg,labelhandles,outH,outM] = legend(varargin)
```

We can see that the 2<sup>nd</sup> output returns some sort of handles. When we investigate further:

```
arrayfun(@class, hT, 'UniformOutput', false)

ans = 

    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Text'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
    'matlab.graphics.primitive.Line'
```

And:

```
hT(1)

ans = 

  Text (This is a very, very long legend text) with properties:

                 String: 'This is a very, very long legend text'
               FontSize: 9
             FontWeight: 'normal'
               FontName: 'Helvetica'
                  Color: [0 0 0]
    HorizontalAlignment: 'left'
               Position: [0.0761 0.5128 0]
                  Units: 'data'

  Show all properties
```

Aha! This is the first legend text entry. We see several interesting properties in the above list (more [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text-properties.html)), but what we care about is `String`.

Then it's a question of how to wrap said string. Fortunately, this is exactly the example provided in the MATLAB documentation for using the python [interface](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/examples/call-python-from-matlab.html), so I will not go into any details of that. Here's a link to the **docs of python's [`textwrap`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/textwrap.html)**. The correct version of the page (selectable by a dropdown on the top left) should correspond to your local python version (see output of [`pyversion`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pyversion.html)).

The rest of my code is just a wrapper around the python interface, to process all legend entries.

#### Explanation (Option 2):

Here we don't use any extra outputs of `legend`, and instead modify `hLeg.PlotChildren.DisplayName`. This property doesn't accept cell arrays of strings (the way for multi-line strings are usually defined in MATLAB), so we need to insert newline "marks" based on syntax the interpreter recognizes (..or character 10 - the ASCII value of a "newline", as shown in [**excaza**'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39456505/3372061)). Finding the correct positions for the line break is still done using python, but this time the strings are `join`ed (with the newline mark in between) instead of being converted to a `cell` column.

#### Notes:

- The 1<sup>st</sup> option probably provides more control at the expense of some additional required tweaking. One may need to play around with the `Text`s' `Position` parameters after wrapping the strings to make the legend look a bit nicer
- Assigning the 2<sup>nd</sup> output of `legend` changes it behavior slightly (you can see it from the overlapping legend entries in the top figure).

Answer (score 4):

For an automated approach that does not require a local Python installation you can specify a maximum character width and use a [regular expression](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) to wrap your text strings accordingly.

For example:

```
function testcode
x = 1:10;
y1 = x;
y2 = 2*x;
y3 = 3*x;
y4 = 4*x;

l = plot(x, y1, x, y2, x, y3, x, y4);
maxwidth = 20; % Maximum character width of each legend string line
ls = {'This is a very very long legend text', 'Test2', 'A bit longer', 'This is quite long'};
ls = cellfun(@(x)wrapstr(x,maxwidth), ls, 'UniformOutput', false);
legend([l(1),l(2),l(3),l(4)], ls, 'Location', 'SouthOutside', 'Orientation', 'horizontal');
end

function [output] = wrapstr(s, width)
% Split input string s into:
%   \S\S{width-1,}: sequences of 1 non-whitespace character followed by 
%                   width-1 or more non-whitespace characters OR
%   .{1, width}: sequences of 1 to width of any character. 
%
%   (?:\\s+|$): Each group is followed by either whitespace or the end of the string
exp = sprintf('(\\S\\S{%u,}|.{1,%u})(?:\\s+|$)', width-1, width);
tmp = regexp(s, exp, 'match');
output = strjoin(deblank(tmp), '\n');
end
```

Which produces:

[image: yay]

---

The regexp matches [Steve Eddin's FEX submission: `linewrap`](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9909-line-wrap-a-string)

Comment: The follow up question obviously is, is whether this can be automated with respect to legend width

Comment: @excaza thanks for your answer. I edited my question, I forgot to tell the general orientation is horizontal - would really appreciate some more help.